# algorithm2e line between for and end not appropriate

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

Has anyone an idea why the line does not match with the first end, but instead with the second?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,bm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\SetAlFnt{\small}
\begin{algorithm} \label{DENalg}
\SetAlgoLined
\caption{Algorithm for DENs}
\BlankLine
\For{number of tasks $t=1,...,T$}{
    \eIf{$t=1$}{
        train weights $\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}$ in layer $\ell \in L$ with
        \begin{align} \label{DENfirsttask}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu\sum_{l=1}^L \| W_l^{t=1} \| _1
        \end{align}
        }{
        selectively retrain $\boldsymbol{W}^{t-1}$ with
        \begin{align} \label{selecretrain}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{L,t}^{t}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_{L,t}^{t}; \boldsymbol{W}_{1:L-1}^{t-1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu \| W_{L,t}^{t} \| _1
        \end{align}
        \If{$w_{i o_t} \neq 0$}{
            add $i$ to selected subnetwork $S$
            }
        \For{$l=L-1,...,1$}{ 
            \If{neuron $j \in S$ exists such that  $\boldsymbol{W}_{l,ij}^{t-1} \neq 0$}{
                add neuron $i$ to $S$}
            }
        obtain $\boldsymbol{W}_S^t$ with
        \begin{align} \label{minW_S}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t}; \boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t-1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu \| W_{S}^{t} \| _2
        \end{align}
        \If{loss $\mathcal{L}_t >$ threshold \tau}{
            add $k$ neurons $\mathbf{h}^{\mathcal{N}}$ at all layers and obtain $\boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}}$ with
            \begin{align} \label{l1l2onS}
              \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{l}^{\mathcal{N}}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}}; {\boldsymbol{W}_l^{t-1}} \mathcal{D}_t) + \mu \| \boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}} \|_1 
              \nonumber \\ + \gamma \sum_g \| \boldsymbol{W}_{l,g}^{\mathcal{N}} \|_{2}
            \end{align}
            }
            \For{$l=L-1,...,1$}{
            \If{$W_{S}^t = 0$}{remove neurons $\mathbf{h}_l^{\mathcal{N}}$}}
        obtain $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$ with
        \begin{align} \label{lastDEN}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}^t}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}^t; \mathcal{D}_t) + \lambda \| \boldsymbol{W}^t - \boldsymbol{W}^{t-1} \|_2^2
        \end{align}
        \For{all hidden units $i$}{
            calculate extent of catastrophic forgetting with 
            \begin{align} \label{extentCF}
                \rho_i^{t} = \| w_{i}^{t} - w_{i}^{t-1} \|_2
            \end{align}
            \If{$\rho_i^{t} >$ threshold \sigma}{
                copy $i$ into new $i'$
                }
            }


        obtain $\boldsymbol{W}^t$ with initial $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$ using \eqref{lastDEN}

        }    
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It printss a very long algorithm, but the only part that is not printed as wished is this:

[image]

Has anyone an idea what's wring? Or may there be an issue with parentheses even before?

My pseudo-code is about 50 lines, could that be an issue?

THANK YOU

Comment: Please make your example into a compilable document rather than just a snippet.

Comment: Yes, sorry; do you think you can see the issue now?

Comment: This is not complete, please make this into a single full document thst others can copy and test as is without having to add anything. Here we have to guess the document class and preamble

Comment: No.  [Complete but minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please.  So give us the smallest possible complete document that we can compile and which shows the problem.  You may find that the process of making a minimal example actually helps you to solve the problem yourself; if this happens please post your own solution as an answer.

Comment: okay, I'm sorry; it should be good now.

Comment: Why are the equations in `align` environments?

Comment: You need some spaces in front of the `\If` and `\For` statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a fair few bugs fixed for you, and using `\equation` instead of `\align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,bm,amsfonts}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\SetAlFnt{\footnotesize}
\begin{algorithm} \label{DENalg}
\SetAlgoLined
\caption{Algorithm for DENs}
\BlankLine
    \For{number of tasks $t=1,...,T$}{
        \eIf{$t=1$}{
            train weights $\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}$ in layer $\ell \in L$ with
        \begin{equation} \label{DENfirsttask}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}^{t=1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu\sum_{l=1}^L \| W_l^{t=1} \| _1
        \end{equation}
    }{
        selectively retrain $\boldsymbol{W}^{t-1}$ with
        \begin{equation}\label{selecretrain}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{L,t}^{t}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_{L,t}^{t}; \boldsymbol{W}_{1:L-1}^{t-1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu \| W_{L,t}^{t} \| _1
        \end{equation}

        \If{$w_{i o_t} \neq 0$}{
            add $i$ to selected subnetwork $S$\strut
        }

        \For{$l=L-1,...,1$}{ 
          \If{neuron $j \in S$ exists such that  $\boldsymbol{W}_{l,ij}^{t-1} \neq 0$}{
              add neuron $i$ to $S$\strut
          }
        }
        obtain $\boldsymbol{W}_S^t$ with
        \begin{equation} \label{minW_S}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t}}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t}; \boldsymbol{W}_{S}^{t-1}, \mathcal{D}_t)+\mu \| W_{S}^{t} \| _2
        \end{equation}

        \If{$\text{loss} \: \mathcal{L}_t > \text{threshold} \: \tau$}{
            add $k$ neurons $\mathbf{h}^{\mathcal{N}}$ at all layers and obtain $\boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}}$ with
            \begin{equation}
                \label{l1l2onS}
                \underset{\boldsymbol{W}_{l}^{\mathcal{N}}}{\text{minimize}} \
                \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}}; {\boldsymbol{W}_l^{t-1}}
                \mathcal{D}_t) + \mu \| \boldsymbol{W}_l^{\mathcal{N}} \|_1 
                 + \gamma \sum_g \| \boldsymbol{W}_{l,g}^{\mathcal{N}} \|_2
            \end{equation}
        }

        \For{$l=L-1,...,1$}{
            \If{$W_{S}^t = 0$}{remove neurons $\mathbf{h}_l^{\mathcal{N}}$}
        }
        obtain $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$ with
        \begin{equation} \label{lastDEN}
            \underset{\boldsymbol{W}^t}{\text{minimize}} \ \mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{W}^t; \mathcal{D}_t) + \lambda \| \boldsymbol{W}^t - \boldsymbol{W}^{t-1} \|_2^2
        \end{equation}

        \For{all hidden units $i$}{
            calculate extent of catastrophic forgetting with 
            \begin{equation} \label{extentCF}
                \rho_i^{t} = \| w_{i}^{t} - w_{i}^{t-1} \|_2
            \end{equation}

            \If{$\rho_i^{t} > \text{threshold} \: \sigma$}{
                copy $i$ into new $i'$
            }
        }

        obtain $\boldsymbol{W}^t$ with initial $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{W}}^t$ using \eqref{lastDEN}
        }    
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The critical thing appears to be to add a blank line before an `\If` or a `\For` if the spacing is wrong.

[image]

And if you really want to split the long equation, then use a `split` environment inside it.